# Coded width is displaying and reporting incorrectly

Tags: css, email, html-email, pardot

We're sending out marketing emails through Pardot and we've encountered a problem where the main table that houses the content is showing up as 640px even though there are several explicit inline and CSS codes setting it to 600px. This is a problem because we set our images to 600px and the extra width creates a visual imbalance. We've tried expanding everything out to 640px as a workaround but we'd love a more robust solution. This also is a relatively new issue.

Under Chrome developer tools, the "Computed" tab reports a width of 640px, but when you expand it to see the computed code, it only reports the original 600px callout.

I've tried editing the code in Chrome, and there's something that's prohibiting it from displaying less than 640px. It'll go wider but not skinnier.

Pardot's email previewer doesn't show this problem, and their rendering tests that predict the email's appearance in different clients all show 600px width. But in all my testing every browser and email client shows the 640px issue once we send an actual test.

I can't find anything in the code to my knowledge that is causing this. Any ideas? Here's a link to view the problem code: http://go.pardot.com/webmail/230162/23104123/8b59c2b28e0bfe75832f8b05f1cffe75db30d7e629d62bb911837a69fb41b773

And here's a link to view the "good" code: http://bfoneill.com/pardottest/

Any help is greatly appreciated. We're not handcuffed, but these go out to a good amount of people and if we could get them looking sharp that'd be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Add `width:100%` to the `img` tag under the title "Video of the Week".

Answer (score 0):

There is padding of 20px around *Video of the week* that is causing the issue. The image is 600px wide and adding 20px padding on the sides makes it 640px. Below is the code fixed.

What I have done to fix the *video of the week* section:

- Removed padding around the
- added padding-left for the heading
- added a table for the copy and adding padding around it

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <!-- Facebook sharing information tags -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="Proof - Subject" />

    <title>Proof - Subject</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FAFAFA" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; background-color: #FAFAFA; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<style type="text/css">#outlook a {
              padding: 0;
          }
          .body{
              width: 100% !important;
              -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
              -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
          }
          .ExternalClass {
              width:100%;
          }
          .ExternalClass,
          .ExternalClass p,
          .ExternalClass span,
          .ExternalClass font,
          .ExternalClass td,
          .ExternalClass div {
              line-height: 100%;
          }
          img {
              outline: none;
              text-decoration: none;
              -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
          }
          a img {
              border: none;
          }
          p {
              margin: 1em 0;
          }
          table td {
              border-collapse: collapse;
          }
          /* hide unsubscribe from forwards*/
          blockquote .original-only, .WordSection1 .original-only {
            display: none !important;
          }

          @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
            body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none !important;} /* Prevent Webkit platforms from changing default text sizes */
            body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Prevent iOS Mail from adding padding to the body */

            #bodyCell{padding:10px !important;}

            #templateContainer{
              max-width:600px !important;
              width:100% !important;
            }

            h1{
              font-size:24px !important;
              line-height:100% !important;
            }

            h2{
              font-size:20px !important;
              line-height:100% !important;
            }

            h3{
              font-size:18px !important;
              line-height:100% !important;
            }

            h4{
              font-size:16px !important;
              line-height:100% !important;
            }


            #templatePreheader{display:none !important;} /* Hide the template preheader to save space */

            #headerImage{
              height:auto !important;
              max-width:600px !important;
              width:100% !important;
            }

            .headerContent{
              font-size:20px !important;
              line-height:125% !important;
            }

            #bodyImage{
              height:auto !important;
              max-width:560px !important;
              width:100% !important;
            }

            .bodyContent{
              font-size:18px !important;
              line-height:125% !important;
            }

            .footerContent{
              font-size:14px !important;
              line-height:115% !important;
            }

            .footerContent a{display:block !important;} /* Place footer social and utility links on their own lines, for easier access */
          }
</style>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="bodyTable" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FAFAFA; border-collapse: collapse !important; height: 100% !important; margin: 0; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; padding: 0; width: 100% !important" width="100%">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="center" id="bodyCell" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; height: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; border-top-width: 0px; border-top-color: #dddddd; border-top-style: solid; margin: 0; padding: 20px;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN TEMPLATE // -->
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateContainer" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-collapse: collapse !important; width: 600px; border: 0px solid #dddddd;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN PREHEADER // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templatePreheader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td align="left" class="preheaderContent" pardot-region="preheader_content00" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #808080; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12.5px; text-align: left; padding: 10px 20px;" valign="top">Welcome to this week's PULSE!</td>
         <td align="left" class="preheaderContent" pardot-region="preheader_content01" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #808080; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 12.5px; text-align: left; padding: 10px 20px 10px 0;" valign="top" width="180">Email not displaying correctly?<br>
         <a href="http://go.pardot.com/webmail/230162/23104123/8b59c2b28e0bfe75832f8b05f1cffe75db30d7e629d62bb911837a69fb41b773" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #606060; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;" target="_blank">View it in your browser</a>.</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END PREHEADER --></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN HEADER // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateHeader" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-collapse: collapse !important; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="">
         <td align="left" class="headerContent" pardot-data="link-underline:underline;" pardot-region="header_image" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 20px; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; padding: 0;" valign="top"><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/2017-05-11/4kz96/23104123"><img alt="Pulse - The Beat of an Active Community" border="0" height="175" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/230162/2017-03-02/5yqj/230162/10489/PulseHeader2017_E.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 175px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="600"></a></td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END HEADER --></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN BODY // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateBody" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-bottom-color: #CCCCCC; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top-color: #FFFFFF; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 0px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="">
         <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-region="body_content00" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 12px; text-align: left; padding: 10px;" valign="top"><span style="font-size:9px;">New look, same great content!</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="">
         <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-region="body_content01" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding: 0 20px;"><br>
         <a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/oors-in-richmond-virginia-html/4kz9d/23104123"><img alt="" height="220" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/230162/2017-05-10/4kxyn/230162/14719/5_11_17A.jpg" style="width: 420px; height: 220px; margin: auto; display: block;" width="420"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="">
         <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-data="" pardot-region="body_content02" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; color: rgb(5, 5, 5); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding: 20px;" valign="top">
         <h2 style="color: #404040 !important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 20px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding-bottom:10px; text-align: left"><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/oors-in-richmond-virginia-html/4kz9d/23104123" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0080C2;">Enjoy Dominion Riverrock and Plenty of Outdoor Adventures in RVA</a></h2>

         <h4 style="display: block; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; font-style: italic; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 14px; margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: left; color: rgb(128, 128, 128) !important;">Travel Pulse</h4>
         Whether going on a stroll through walkable neighborhoods, relaxing along the riverfront, or taking part in Dominion Riverrock, the country's largest outdoor music and sports festival, Richmond has a lot to offer. <a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/oors-in-richmond-virginia-html/4kz9d/23104123" style="color:#0080C2;"><em>Read More</em></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="" class="">
         <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-region="body_content02" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding: 20px;" valign="top"><span style="color:#0080C2;"><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/orward-active-learning-summit-/4kz9g/23104123"><img align="left" alt="" border="0" height="100" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/230162/2017-05-10/4kxys/230162/14723/5_11_17B.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 10px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="100"></a><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/orward-active-learning-summit-/4kz9g/23104123" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0080C2;"><span style="font-size: 16px;"><b>Movement Makers Attendees Ready for Active
Learning&nbsp;</b></span></a></span>
         <h4 style="color: #808080 !important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 14px; margin: 0; padding-bottom:10px; text-align: left">Sports Backers Blog</h4>
         <span style="color:#000000;">The&nbsp;Movement Makers National Active Living Summit presented by VCU Health&nbsp;takes place May 17-19 and there’s no better way to illustrate what you’ll learn at the Summit&nbsp;than to hear from those attending.</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/orward-active-learning-summit-/4kz9g/23104123" style="color:#0080C2;" target="_blank"><em>Read More</em></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="">
         <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-data="" pardot-region="body_content02" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; color: rgb(5, 5, 5); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding: 20px;" valign="top"><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/you-can-apply-to-everyday-life/4kz9j/23104123"><img align="left" alt="Record Attendance for Virginia State Parks in 2016 - Thumbnail" border="0" height="100" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/230162/2017-05-11/4kz54/230162/14763/5_11_17C.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 10px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="100"></a><span style="font-size:16px;"><strong><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/you-can-apply-to-everyday-life/4kz9j/23104123" style="text-decoration:none;"><font color="#0080c2">10 Classic Running Rules to Apply to Everyday Life</font></a></strong></span>
         <h4 style="color: #808080 !important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 14px; margin: 0; padding-bottom:10px; text-align: left">Runner's World</h4>
         The main principles that make you a better runner can also help you out in other areas of your everyday life. <a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/you-can-apply-to-everyday-life/4kz9j/23104123" style="color:#0080C2;"><em>Read More</em></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="">
         <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-region="body_content02" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding: 20px;" valign="top">
         <h2 style="display: block; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 20px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; color: rgb(64, 64, 64) !important; text-align: center;"><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/2017-05-11/4kz9l/23104123"><img alt="" border="0" height="82" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/230162/2017-03-22/2dkd4/230162/11497/movement_makers_2.jpg" style="width: 272px; height: 82px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="272"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/2017-05-11/4kz9n/23104123"><img alt="" border="0" height="82" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/230162/2017-05-11/4kz4z/230162/14761/Riverrock2017_PulseAd.jpg" style="width: 272px; height: 82px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="272"></a></h2>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="">
         <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-region="body_content02" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding: 20px;" valign="top"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><span style="color:#0080C2;"><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/biking-opportunities-richmond-/4kz9q/23104123"><img align="left" alt="" border="0" height="100" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/230162/2017-05-11/4kz5v/230162/14771/5_11_17D.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 10px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="100"></a><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/biking-opportunities-richmond-/4kz9q/23104123" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0080C2;">Biking Opportunities for All in
RVA</a></span></span></strong>

<h4 style="color: #808080 !important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 14px; margin: 0; padding-bottom:10px; text-align: left">Boomer Magazine</h4>
<span style="color:#000000;">Whether you're cruising the countryside, riding around the city, or exploring the Virginia Capital Trail, cycling in RVA can be just about whatever you want to make it.</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/biking-opportunities-richmond-/4kz9q/23104123" style="color:#0080C2;"><em>Read More</em></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="">
         <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-region="body_content02" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding: 20px;" valign="top"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><span style="color:#0080C2;"><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/5-000-steps-a-day-11109289-php/4kz9s/23104123" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0080C2;"><img align="left" alt="" border="0" height="100" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/230162/2017-05-11/4kz62/230162/14777/5_11_17E.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 10px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="100">15 Tips for Getting in 15,000 Steps A Day</a></span></span></strong>

<h4 style="color: #808080 !important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 14px; margin: 0; padding-bottom:10px; text-align: left">Houston Chronicle</h4>
<span style="color:#000000;">Moving more throughout the day will not only reduce your risks for cardiovascular disease, but also significantly improve your health. Use these tips to hit that 15,000 step mark each day</span>.&nbsp;<a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/5-000-steps-a-day-11109289-php/4kz9s/23104123" style="color:#0080C2;"><em>Read More</em></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="" class="">
         <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-region="body_content02" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding: 20px;" valign="top"><strong><span style="font-size:16px;"><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/the-name-game-part-2-/4kz9v/23104123" style="text-decoration:none;color:blue;"><span style="color:#0080C2;"><img align="left" alt="" border="0" height="100" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/230162/2017-05-11/4kz6b/230162/14779/5_11_17F.jpg" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; float: left; margin: 10px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="100">The Bicycle Name Game</span></a></span></strong>
         <h4 style="color: #808080 !important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; font-style: italic; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 14px; margin: 0; padding-bottom:10px; text-align: left">Bicycle Times</h4>
         <span style="color:#000000;">Ever wonder who comes up with the names for bikes? It turns out the process can be one of the most fun, and frustrating, jobs in the bike industry.</span>&nbsp;<a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/the-name-game-part-2-/4kz9v/23104123" style="color:#0080C2;"><em>Read More</em></a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="">
         <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-region="body_content02" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left;" valign="top">
         <h2 style="color: #404040 !important; display: block; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 20px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0; padding-bottom:10px; text-align: left; padding-left:20px;">Video of the Week</h2>
         <a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/ee-video-outdoors-in-the-city-/4kz9x/23104123"><img alt="" border="0" height="220" src="http://go.pardot.com/l/230162/2017-05-11/4kz6v/230162/14781/5_11_17V.jpg" style="width: 600px; height: 220px; margin: auto; display: block; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="600"></a>
         
         <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:0px 20px 20px 20px;-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #505050; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left;"><br>
          <em>Outdoors in the City: </em>Local filmmaker and outdoor enthusiast Christian Wood put together this short film titled 'Outdoors in the City,' highlighting a few of Richmond's most popular outdoor pursuits including rock climbing, mountain biking, and kayaking. Take a look and enjoy!</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

         
         
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr pardot-repeatable="">
         <td align="left" class="bodyContent" pardot-data="" pardot-region="body_content02" style="text-size-adjust: 100%; color: rgb(80, 80, 80); font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 14px; line-height: 21px; text-align: left; padding: 20px; background: rgb(235, 235, 235);" valign="top">
         <h2 style="display: block; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 20px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; color: rgb(64, 64, 64) !important; text-align: center;"><img alt="Sports Backers logo" border="0" height="77" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/bf557814b3f56342081fd24da/images/3a365d9a-f14e-40dd-aa00-e4b31f667681.png" style="width: 200px; height: 77px; border-width: 0px; border-style: solid;" width="200"></h2>

         <h3 style="display: block; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 20px; font-style: normal; font-weight: bold; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: 20px; margin: 0px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; color: rgb(64, 64, 64) !important;">Who is Sports Backers?</h3>

         <div style="text-align: center;">We're a non-profit organization, dedicated to building a more active community!&nbsp;<a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/01M9m6-form-00Pj0000001pUouEAE/4kz9z/23104123" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0981c5;" target="_blank">Donate</a>, <a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/16008197-2021115962-1479224348/4kzb2/23104123" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0981c5;" target="_blank">volunteer</a>&nbsp;or <a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/events-/4kzb4/23104123" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0981c5;" target="_blank">enter an event</a> to help support our mission!</div>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END BODY --></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td align="center" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt;" valign="top"><!-- BEGIN FOOTER // -->
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="templateFooter" style="-ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse !important; border-top-color: #FFFFFF; border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 0px; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt" width="100%">
       <tbody>
        <tr pardot-removable="">
         <td align="left" class="footerContent" pardot-region="footer_content00" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #808080; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px; text-align: left; padding: 20px;" valign="top">
         <div style="text-align: center;">Have some thoughts, suggestions, or story ideas? Email <a href="mailto:pulse@sportsbackers.org">pulse@sportsbackers.org</a><br>
         <br>
         &nbsp;<a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/offer-addthis-unique-lng-en-us/4kzb6/23104123" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #606060; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;">Forward to Friend</a>&nbsp;</div>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td align="left" class="footerContent" pardot-region="footer_content01" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #808080; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px; text-align: left; padding: 0 20px 20px;" valign="top">
         <div style="text-align: center;"><em>Copyright © 2017, All rights reserved.</em><br>
         <br>
         <strong>Our mailing address is:</strong><br>
         <br/>Sports Backers<br/>100 Avenue of Champions<br/>Richmond, VA 23230<br/></div>
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td align="left" class="footerContent original-only" pardot-region="footer_content02" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; color: #808080; font-family: Helvetica; font-size: 10px; line-height: 15px; text-align: left; padding: 0 20px 20px;" valign="top">
         <div style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://go.pardot.com/unsubscribe/u/230162/8b59c2b28e0bfe75832f8b05f1cffe75db30d7e629d62bb911837a69fb41b773/23104123" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; color: #606060; font-weight: normal; text-decoration: underline;">unsubscribe from all emails</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/nameurl-tfa-1951-3last-nameurl/4kz9b/23104123/-.-/brandon%40sportsbackers.org/Brandon/O%26%2339%3BNeill" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;  font-weight: normal; color: #606060;">update subscription preferences</a><a href="http://go.pardot.com/e/230162/nameurl-tfa-1951-3last-nameurl/4kz9b/23104123/-.-/brandon%40sportsbackers.org/Brandon/O%26%2339%3BNeill">&nbsp;</a></div>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
      <!-- // END FOOTER --></td>
     </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <!-- // END TEMPLATE --></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<br>
<!--
          This email was originally designed by the wonderful folks at MailChimp and remixed by Pardot.
          It is licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0
        -->
</body>
</html>   <script type="text/javascript">
piAId = '231162';
piCId = '1478';

(function() {
 function async_load(){
  var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript';
  s.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://pi' : 'http://cdn') + '.pardot.com/pd.js';
  var c = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; c.parentNode.insertBefore(s, c);
 }
 if(window.attachEvent) { window.attachEvent('onload', async_load); }
 else { window.addEventListener('load', async_load, false); }
})();
</script>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Cheers